# How are multi-platform applications developed?

Tags: multiplatform

I was wondering how multi-platform applications are developed. Applications like Microsoft Office for MAC/Windows, FireFox for MAC/Windows/Linux etc.

If they have to code for different platforms then it's hard to manage and there are lots of other complexities involved.

Q: How do development teams manage the complexity of developing for multiple platforms?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft office is not a multi-platform application. If you've ever used the Mac version you'd know. The last multi-platform version of Office was the infamous Office 6.0 way back in 1998. What happened was users moaned about the look-and-feel and decried the 'porting' mentality.

The Mac version of Office is not only written by a different team, it is written by a completely different department: The Mac Business Unit, also known as the MacBU. Different head of department, different managers and I believe different sales and marketing people as well.

That is one way of doing it. Also known as "the proper way" among Mac users.

Of course, not everyone is Microsoft's size and can afford to create a completely different subsidiary just to support Mac users (much less Linux users). The slightly more sane way of doing it is to use a cross platform library for the GUI stuff like [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org) or QT or GTK. After all, most of your core C code isn't going to change much accross platforms, just the proprietary stuff like GUI and file management. Heck, you can even stick to POSIX function call for file management and networking for cross-platforminess. But be warned, there is a high chance of Mac users hating the end result (like what happened to MS Office 6.0).

The third way is the middle way. Keep the common, core application code separate from the proprietary GUI stuff (which is a good idea anyway in terms of maintainability). The MVC design pattern is a good way of doing this. Have a way (using #define or diferent build script/makefiles) to switch the View and Controller components of your MVC framework. This is what Google does with Chrome. The Mac version uses native Mac graphics and the Windows/Linux version uses a graphics engine called [Skia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skia_Graphics_Engine). The core of Chrome is WebKit and V8 both of which are cross platform.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably almost as many approaches to this as there are multi-platform applications.  In general, they would boil down to a few different strategies:

1. Use a language with a portable runtime - Java for example, .NET to a lesser extent, or any of a zillion different interpreted scripting languages.
2. Use a cross-platform toolkit (e.g. QT) to hide the platform differences.
3. Use conditional compilation in a language like C or C++ to change the codebase for different platforms.  This is similar to #2, except that you are essentially building your own cross-platform toolkit inside of your app.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking compiled C++, you end up with some conditional defines, like `#IFDEF WIN32` in a few places in the code. When you are writing cross platform code, you must test cross platform. A build system like Hudson that can build your code on all platforms when you check-in helps.

For GUI stuff, use of a good cross platform library like QT is extreemly helpfull. It lets you write your gui code more or less the same way, but keeps the native feel on whatever system it is compiled for.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

A primary approach for multi-platform code, is a multi-platform base.  For example, C++ code that makes liberal use of the boost library (for file access, thread synchronization primitives, etc) will work in a multi-platform setting.  Likewise, if you create .net (managed) code, then your cross platform capability is achieved by the .net run-time (if on windows) or by Mono (if on Linux systems).

There are more matters than these to address, but this is the biggest.  Other matters can include, in the case of C++, how the GUI is handled.  A deliberate choice to use cross-platform code again plays its part - such as using WxWidgets or Qt.

It is also helpful to have a [cross-platform build](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/28696/1954?pf=true) process.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a Hardware/Operating System abstraction layer.  You create your application in C or C++ using the Standard C Library or equivalent code that isn't dependent on the platform you're targeting.

For OS or hardware-specific interfaces (like the load/save dialog, printing, toolbars, notifications, etc.), you create a generalized API for your application to use, and then code two separate implementations -- one for each of the targeted platforms.

When dealing with file formats or network protocols, it may be necessary to include code to convert multi-byte values between the host byte order (which could be big or little-endian) and the correct endian-ness required by the file/network protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Q: How do development teams manage the complexity of developing for multiple platforms?

A: good regression tests.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to have a separate class for each platform specific functionality and have all the classes needed for a particular platform compiled together. This way the code is cleaner and it also avoids unnecessary abstraction. Here is an example of ["Upload XML data to MySQL or NoSQL"](http://oodupinc.blogspot.com/2016/11/defaulthandler-uploadfilestring-read.html)
Blue color is for NoSQL and pink for SQL, khaki color is for common code and grey is language support.